# What is the purpose of app.config file in ASP.NET Core web application (.NET Framework)?

Tags: garbage-collection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET Core web application (.NET Framework) there is `app.config` file which contains:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

but this file is not available in ASP.NET Core web application (.NET Core) project. running `GC` in `server` mode is necessary for ASP.NET Core web application (.NET Framework) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an equivalent in the web app, you're looking for `project.json` and it's `runtimeOptions`. I detailed this a little in my [migration guide](https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/), (look for `runtimeOptions`).

The addition of the `gsServer` is to tell the `runtime` to perform garbage collection. The server in the context of the **ASP.NET Core** application is *Kestrel*. There are various details about this in the `project.json` schema changes [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/175). The documentation states this:

> Enable server GC

Additionally, you should look at the following:

- [Host Configuration Knobs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md#host-configuration-knobs)
- [Rutime Configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/v1.0.0-rc2/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md#runtimeoptions-section-runtimeconfigjson)

Comment: Why exactly do we need app.config file even though we can just have it in project.json? Can't both .NET Core and .NET Framework read from there? Another interesting question is what happens is what happens without this flag -> no garbage collection at all, this would probably not be any valid scenario...